# How to handle background overly in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dependencies

I'm trying to pass a menu in my overlay box in the app but the menu is opening behind the overlay box and exceeding the size of the box whereas it should open within the overlay box and should not exceed the size of the box, it should be more likely a dropdown calander menu into one box, can anyone suggest me a solution on my problem?

Below is the method where I'm defining the menu in my overlay box

[image: here is the picture for your understanding]

```
 void showTranslationResult(
    BuildContext resultcontext,
    PdfTextSelectionChangedDetails resultdetails,
    String translatedText,
  ) async {
    final RenderBox overlay =
        Overlay.of(resultcontext).context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

    const translationBoxWidth = 200.0;
    const translationBoxHeight = 250.0;

    final position =
        overlay.globalToLocal(resultdetails.globalSelectedRegion!.bottomRight);
    final translationBoxLeft = position.dx;
    final translationBoxTop = position.dy - (translationBoxHeight / 2);

    late OverlayEntry translationOverlayEntry;

    translationOverlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (tcontext) {
        return Positioned(
            left: translationBoxLeft,
            top: translationBoxTop,
            height: translationBoxHeight,
            width: translationBoxWidth,
            child: Material(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

                  children: [
                    // Dropdown for language selection
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: DropdownButton(
                        value: selectedTargetLanguage,
                        items: supportedLanguages
                            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                              (String language) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: language,
                                child: Text(language),
                              ),
                            )
                            .toList(),
                        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                          // Update the selected target language
                          if (newValue != null) {
                            selectedTargetLanguage = newValue;
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),

                    Expanded(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(
                            translatedText,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        translationOverlayEntry.remove();
                        _translationOverlayEntry = null;
                        enableTranslateButton();
                      },
                      child: const Text('Close'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
      },
    );

    if (_translationOverlayEntry != null) {
      _translationOverlayEntry!.remove();
      _translationOverlayEntry = null;
    }

    Overlay.of(resultcontext).insert(translationOverlayEntry);
    isTranslationBoxOpen = false;
  }
```